# Fopen a .txt file using a regex

Tags: php, regex, filenames, fopen

I need to open a .txt file whose I know the directory path but not the entire name. I just know some unique numbers that are part of its name.

I've checked PHP.net and google a little bit but didn't find anything useful.

In your opinion is it possible to do something to achieve this?

For example: I have these unique numbers that are part of the filename ("9129129"), and I know the path to the directory where this and other files are stored ("/Home/Library/ApplicationSupport/project"). The file itself is a .txt, and can be something like "xyz124124 fbqwf9129129 fwehbj$124.txt".

Comment: Anything is possible, Share the format , an example or code please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`glob`](http://php.net/glob) function to do a match for a .txt file with some sub-string:

```
$substring = "9129129";
$path      = '/Home/Library/ApplicationSupport/project/';

list($name) = glob(sprintf("$path*%d*.txt", $substring), GLOB_NOSORT) + array(NULL);
if ($name) {
    $file = fopen($path . $name, "r");
    // Do something with `$file`        
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! However I have to use PHP 5.3.5. And the code isn't working properly. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex here, just ordinary [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function where you can give your search pattern:

```
$files = glob('/Home/Library/ApplicationSupport/project/*9129129*.txt');
print_r( $files ); # or foreach $files array and do your magic
```

Comment: Worked nicely in my situation. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]+\.(txt)$ should work
```